# Not able to unfollow users using Twitter API Client

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am trying to unfollow a user using twitter api for android,

Endpoint :https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/destroy.json ([doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/post-friendships-destroy))

Java Code:

Interface:

```js
interface GetUnfollowService{
    @POST("/1.1/friendships/destroy.json")
    Call<ResponseBody> destroy(@Query("user_id") Long userID);
}
```

MyTwitterApiClient.java

```
class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
    super(session);
}



public GetUserData getUserData(){return  getService(GetUserData.class);}

public GetUnfollowService getUnfollowService(){ return  getService(GetUnfollowService.class);}
```

My Application:

```
                TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(twitterSession);

            Long userID  = userTwitterData.getNot_following_back_ids().get(i);

            Call<ResponseBody> cb = myTwitterApiClient.getUnfollowService().destroy(userID);

            cb.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<ResponseBody> result) {
                    Toast.makeText(NonFollowers.this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(NonFollowers.this, "Bye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

I am receiving HTTP error 401, can someone please tell where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you also have code in your app to enable the user to login to Twitter? That's not clear from what you have shared here.

Comment: I was using the app authentication, whereas for `POST` operation we need to use user authentication of twitter.